# Libgdx with android xml?

Tags: android, xml, libraries, libgdx

I'm using the libraries LIBGDX to make an application and be able to run on both Android as a computer. I'd like to introduce a new library to create graphs in android, but do not know if I can add libraries that are for use with Android and libgdx and also running on the computer.
Nor if you can work in a similar way to how you normally program in android, and I want to do the designs from the GUI of android that I'm used to and I find it more comfortable. Also when the xml type strings.xml for example, I wonder if I can use them or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to build libraries (really, any code at all) that runs with libGDX:

1. Use only the libGDX-provided APIs.  For example, if you render your graphs with the OpenGL wrapper provided by libGDX, it will work everywhere.  Or if you use the "scene2d" UI APIs, it will work everywhere.
2. Implement a generic front-end library that uses libGDX APIs, and then calls out to backend-specific libraries that implement platform-specific bits.  For your example, that would entail building an Android-based backend that perhaps used Android-specific UI rendering, and then building a separate desktop-based backend that perhaps used Swing or some other Java-desktop-specific APIs.

If all of your code is using the second approach, you're not really getting much benefit from libGDX.